# Object has no attribute "dlg"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am creating a QGIS plugin and want to list the layers loaded in a Combobox when writing `self.dlg` the error message `object has no attribute` appears. I am new in this domain. The code below is for the function.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication, Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from .resources import *

from .mapping_utilities_dockwidget import MappingUtilitiesDockWidget
import os.path

  def loadLayers(self):
        self.dlg.cb_inputlayers.clear()
        layers = [layer for layer in  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
        network_component=[]
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.type() ==QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                network_component.append(layer.name())
        self.dlg.cb_inputlayers.addItems(network_component)
```

Comment: Your `dlg` object is not defined. Have you designed a form with Qt Designer or Qt Creator ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo I have used Qt Creator

Comment: And have you a `.ui` file or a `.py` file for your form ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo both files are available

Comment: Is `mapping_utilities_dockwidget` your `.py` form ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo , yes the file is in py but I cannot add its content here , its larger than the accepted number of words

Comment: so I will use it as an object itself, thanks @J.Monticolo for your help, I will try it

Comment: If you don't write a class, don't use `self`. Just add lines :
```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDockWidget
...
dock = QDockWidget()
dlg = MappingUtilitiesDockWidget()
dlg.setupUi(dock)
dlg.cb_inputlayers.clear()
...
```

Comment: For simplify plugin development, I advise you to use this tool : https://g-sherman.github.io/plugin_build_tool/

Comment: And before that, you may use the plugin builder and study the structure of a plugin.